# Npm MongoDB "Module not found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-start

everyone from past months I have this issue when I create new package and I run

> npm start
> It returns me this error:
> [image]
> It doesnt matter what is inside it returns me this kind of error for every new project
> this is the current package.json:

```
{
  "name": "section-7",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

It is single app and inside there I have only app.js

[image]

I try to install globally mongoDb.
I try to show the path from Windows Envrinmonet variables to mongodb
What helps me is that I use yarn but I want to use and npm for running it. Thank you all

Comment: is that your entire package.json? cause if so it doesn't look like you've included any modules whatsoever other than body-parser and express. Youll need to run `npm i packagename`  Also the error msg you show is regarding missing dependency nodemon and the answer posted shows how to properly install that as a dev dependency

Comment: This is for every project I create. When I use npm init and and start the server it appear this error

Comment: Okay but so you only include 2 dependencies body-parser & express. you don't include any module for MongoDB try adding this as a dependency. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb and run `npm install mongodb` and then re run the project